# Creating Triggers to insert into a table where the table is altered by other application

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a database in my local machine which is actually updated by an online application.

I want to **create triggers** for a particular table ( say table1) such that it inserts values (From Table1) into another table (say table2).

Is it possible as I have no control over the online application, if so how to create the trigger in following condition

In table1, I was column1(PK),column2,column3,column4 to be inserted into table2,

where online application changes column2, at the same time the NULL values in the table1.column3 and table1.column4 will be filled by the online application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a trigger in the database.  This will execute no matter how the data gets modified.  Triggers can act before or after an insert, update, or delete.  In your case I believe you would want a before insert trigger.  For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2
        (column1, columnn2, column3, column4)
    VALUES
        new.column1, new.column2, new.column3, new.column4;
END;
```

The [SQLite create trigger documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) outlines the syntax.  You can also check the MySQL documentation as well.  Search for `mysql trigger`.

Comment: Can u expand a bit more? I am clueless.